# A box for comments

Tags: javascript, io, ecmascript-6, react.js

I made this as a practice application to learn React. It is simply a box where someone can enter their name and a comment and submit it, and display other comments. This animated GIF illustrates what it looks like:

[image: comments]

*Note: Please don't be too critical of the looks, I haven't spent a lot of time styling it with CSS. Also those small vertical lines shown with the typing were introduced by imgur when I uploaded the gif to it, those don't appear on the actual page.*

---

There is not a data persistence server/layer to speak of, as it is not meant to be actually deployed, so I simply keep the data into a regular array of objects, like so:

```
var comments = [
  {
    id: 1,
    author: "John Q. Commenter",
    text: "This is the first comment.",
    timestamp: new Date()
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    author: "Jane A. Opinionated",
    text: "This is the second comment.",
    timestamp: new Date()
  },
  /* Test for empty comment */
  {
    id: 3
  }
]
```

I went with a Component/Container design approach, where the container is responsible for the business logic, and the container is only responsible for rendering the appearance of the objects on the page.

There are 4 components together in this hierarchy:

> ```
> CommentBox
> |- CommentList
>    |- Comment
> |- CommentForm
> ```

The data flow for comments is essentially: `CommentForm -> comments (array) -> CommentList -> Comment`.

I will focus on the React files only, but if you are curious about the rest you can [look at the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Phrancis/react-comments).

Note that I left out the `import React from 'react'` and `export default` lines because every file begins and ends with those, respectively.

---

#### index.jsx

This is the entry point:

```
import CommentBox from './containers/CommentBoxContainer'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CommentBox/>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

---

## CommentBox

This component is meant to hold all the other elements together:

```
import CommentListContainer from '../containers/CommentListContainer'
import CommentFormContainer from '../containers/CommentFormContainer'

const CommentBox = (props) => (
  <div className="commentBox">
    <h1 className="commentBoxHeader">
      Comments
    </h1>
    <CommentListContainer data={props.data}/>
    <CommentFormContainer />
  </div>
)

CommentBox.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

#### CommentBoxContainer

This container doesn't contain any business logic.

```
import CommentBox from '../components/CommentBox'

class CommentBoxContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CommentBox/>
    )
  }
}
```

---

## CommentList

This component has a function to map the fields contained in each object in the `comments` array to be displayed each into a `Comment` component, which are then injected into a `<div>`.

```
import CommentContainer from '../containers/CommentContainer'

const CommentList = (props) => {
  // Parse comment data into a list of comments to be rendered:
  let commentNodes = props.data.map(function(comment) {
    return (
      <CommentContainer
        id={comment.id}
        author={comment.author}
        timestamp={comment.timestamp}
      >
        {comment.text}
      </CommentContainer>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div className="commentList">
      {commentNodes}
    </div>
  )
}

CommentList.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.array
}
```

#### CommentListContainer

The container is responsible for polling the `comments` array for data changes at a specific interval (I set it for 2 seconds), and if changes are detected it will render an updated `CommentList` to the page.

Note that I am aware that this would be better done with websockets or some other mechanism, I just didn't get around to implementing that yet

```
import CommentList from '../components/CommentList'
import comments from '../data/comments'

class CommentListContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      numComments: 0
    }
    this.POLL_INTERVAL = 2000
    this.updateComments = this.updateComments.bind(this)
    this.poll = this.poll.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._timer = setInterval(this.poll, this.POLL_INTERVAL)
    if (comments) {
      this.updateComments()
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this._timer) {
      clearInterval(this._timer)
      this._timer = null
    }
  }

  updateComments() {
    this.setState({
      data: comments,
      numComments: this.state.data.length
    })
  }

  poll() {
    if (comments && comments.length != this.state.numComments) {
      this.updateComments()
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.data !== []) {
      return (
        <CommentList data={this.state.data}/>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Comment

This renders the actual comment formatting and content onto the page, after the data is passed from the `CommentList`. Each `className` attribute maps to a CSS class. I added some `defaultProps` to deal with missing fields in the objects, as can be seen in the 3rd comment in the screenshot.

I elected not to set a default value for `timestamp` and instead replace it with the string `"unknown date"` if it was missing/undefined.

```
import formatTimestamp from '../utils/formatTimestamp'

const Comment = (props) => (
  <div className="comment">
    <p className="commentText">
      {props.children}
    </p>
    <span className="commentAuthor">
      - {props.author}
    </span>
    <span className="commentTimestamp">
      , posted on {props.timestamp ? formatTimestamp(props.timestamp) : "unknown date"}
    </span>
  </div>
)

Comment.defaultProps = {
  author:   <em>(author unknown)</em>,
  children: <em>(empty)</em>
}

Comment.propTypes = {
  author:     React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children:   React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  timestamp:  React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

It also uses a simple formatting function that I made, called `formatTimestamp`, to display it as US-formatted locale like "Sunday, Oct 23, 2016, 10:53 PM".

```
function formatTimestamp(timestamp) {
  var options = {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit"
  }
  return timestamp.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options)
}
```

#### CommentContainer

This container also has no business logic in it.

```
import Comment from '../components/Comment'

class CommentContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Comment
        author={this.props.author}
        timestamp={this.props.timestamp}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Comment>
    )
  }
}
```

---

## CommentForm

This component renders 2 text inputs, a submit button, and a Twitter-style character counter. I passed it 3 callback functions from `CommentFormContainer` to handle `onSubmit` and `onChange` events and thus overriding the browser's automatic handling of the inputs.

```
const CommentForm = (props) => (
  <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
    <h3 className="commentFormHeader">Post a comment:</h3>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="author">Name: </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="author"
        placeholder="Your name"
        value={props.author}
        onChange={props.onAuthorChange}
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="comment">Comment: </label>
      <br />
      <textarea
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        name="comment"
        value={props.comment}
        onChange={props.onCommentChange}
      />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
    <p>{props.charsLeft}/{props.charLimit}</p>
  </form>
)

CommentForm.defaultProps = {
  author: '',
  comment: '',
  charsLeft: 0,
  charLimit: 0
}

CommentForm.propTypes = {
  author:           React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  comment:          React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  charsLeft:        React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onAuthorChange:   React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onCommentChange:  React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

#### CommentFormContainer

This container is responsible for a few things:

- Handle `onChange` and `onSubmit` events passed from `CommentForm`
- Set and enforce the character limit
- Build and push new comment objects into the `comments` array
- *Future: give each entry a unique ID*

Its state contains the data that is entered on the form as well as the count of characters that are in the `<textarea>` input.

```
import CommentForm from '../components/CommentForm'
import comments from '../data/comments'

const CHARACTER_LIMIT = 200

class CommentFormContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      author: '',
      comment: '',
      charsLeft: CHARACTER_LIMIT
    }
    this.handleAuthorChange = this.handleAuthorChange.bind(this)
    this.handleCommentChange = this.handleCommentChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleAuthorChange(event) {
    this.setState({ author: event.target.value })
  }

  handleCommentChange(event) {
    var input = event.target.value
    var length = input.length
    if (length <= CHARACTER_LIMIT) {
      this.setState({
        comment: input,
        charsLeft: CHARACTER_LIMIT - length
      })
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let author = this.state.author
    let comment = this.state.comment
    let timestamp = new Date()
    if (!author || !comment) {
      return
    }
    // TODO generate an actual ID, such as GUID/UUID
    comments.push({
      id: 42,
      author: this.state.author,
      text: this.state.comment,
      timestamp: timestamp
    })
    this.setState({
      author: '',
      comment: '',
      charsLeft: CHARACTER_LIMIT
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CommentForm
        author={this.state.author}
        comment={this.state.comment}
        charsLeft={this.state.charsLeft}
        charLimit={CHARACTER_LIMIT}
        onAuthorChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
        onCommentChange={this.handleCommentChange}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no particularly compelling reason to make `CommentBoxContainer` a class instead of a Stateless Functional Component, like most of the rest of the items here.

`CommentContainer` also could be a SFC.

---

In `CommentListContainer`, I would set:

```
this.state = { data: this.props.data || [], numComments: this.props.data && this.props.data.length || 0 }
```

However, that is probably likely exactly the same as setting the data initially in `componentDidMount`, I've just not currently used it like that, as all of my components tend to not hang around, so constructor is always called right before `componentDidMount()`.

I'd also consider moving the poll query up to `CommentBox`, considering that's where you start using the `data` var in your chain.

---

I also see that `CommentBox` has a required prop for `data`, but you're not actually using it.  So that can probably be removed.

---

I'm a bit confused by the decision to have a separate `CommentForm` and `CommentFormContainer` -- I mean, I guess if you were planning to support getting data from some source other than React State, that might make sense.. but otherwise, it seems a bit convoluted to have a component and then have it's state kept in another component.

Comment: Thanks, Phrancis, I haven't been around here much and completely forgot about formatting. Much appreciated, and I'll try to do better next time.